# how to download partial content from remote video url in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, backend, nodejs-stream

I have the following code to download a specific part (range) of a video using nodejs http.get(),

```
const fileUrl = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4'
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('https')
const fileName = 'video.mp4'
const options = {
hostname: 'https://www.example.com',
path: '/path/to/video.mp4',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
'range': 'bytes=0-444444', //the size I'm requesting is the first 444.4 kB of the video
}

const req = http.get(options)
req.on('response', (res) => {
console.log(res.headers) //just to see headers
})

req.on('response', (res) => {
let file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)
let size
res.on('data', (chunk) => {
file.write(chunk)
size = fs.statSync(file.path).size
console.log(size)
})
})
```

the problem is when I set `'range'` header to `'range': 'bytes=0-anyValue'` the downloaded video can be played normally, but when I set `'range'` to `'range': 'bytes=[anyValue>0]-anyValue'` the downloaded video is corrupted and can't be played.

when `'range': 'bytes=0-anyValue'` incoming response headers are

```
{

'content-length': '444445',

'content-range': 'bytes 0-444444/17449469',

'accept-ranges': 'bytes',

'last-modified': 'Tue, 07 May 2019 11:45:38 GMT',

etag: '"f13a255d30ef81d2abf8ba2e4fefc2fd-1"',

'x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs': 'md5:4e3127acff74ac20b52e1680a5e0779d',

'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',

'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="Rim.Of.The.World.2019.720p.Trailer.mp4";',

'content-encoding': 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding',

'x-amz-request-id': 'tx0000000000000001bfccc-00602060b1-1b3f92b-default',

'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',

date: 'Sun, 07 Feb 2021 21:50:41 GMT',

connection: 'close'

}
```

and the downloaded video is playable

but when `'range': 'bytes=[anyValue>0]-anyValue` incoming response headers are

```
{

'content-length': '443890',

'content-range': 'bytes 555-444444/17449469',

'accept-ranges': 'bytes',

'last-modified': 'Tue, 07 May 2019 11:45:38 GMT',

etag: '"f13a255d30ef81d2abf8ba2e4fefc2fd-1"',

'x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs': 'md5:4e3127acff74ac20b52e1680a5e0779d',

'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',

'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="Rim.Of.The.World.2019.720p.Trailer.mp4";',

'content-encoding': 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding',

'x-amz-request-id': 'tx00000000000000e8c5225-006020613d-1afef1a-default',

'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',

date: 'Sun, 07 Feb 2021 21:53:01 GMT',

connection: 'close'

}
```

and the downloaded video is CORRUPTED and NOT playable

What I'm I doing wrong?

and How to achieve my goal properly?

Thanks in advance.